# Inserting Wordpress shortcodes in modalbox

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So I am trying to make a modalbox which displays a contact form upon clicking on a "Contact Me" button.

I am trying to do this using jQuery, and I am using Contact Forms 7 with which I can use a shortcode to display a form.  My problem is that I don't exactly know how should I proceed with this.

Any help or pointers towards more info on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP you could do this,

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[whatever_shortcode param1="value" param2="value" ]'); ?>
```

But the shortcode must be previously registered. If it's a third party plugins, it should be registered, but if you are developing your own code and maybe a plugin I think is done something like this... and it must be added to your theme functions.php

```
// [bartag foo="foo-value"]
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    return "foo = {$a['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

more info, https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

And to run it with JS/jQuery, maybe loading the page with content hidden, and then use JS to show it
...